# Efecto jquery que solo suceda por cada elemento clickable

Tags: php, jquery

Muy buenas, tengo un foreach hecho de esta manera:

```
 <?php if ($beratung): ?>
      <?php foreach ($beratung as $beratungen): ?>
            <span class="is-flex">
                 <img class="arrow" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/pfeil_runter.svg"/>
                 <?php echo $beratungen['frage']; ?>
           </span>
           <div class="antwort">
                <?php echo $beratungen['antwort']; ?>
           </div>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Al que le tengo asignado un efecto jquery que lo que hace es que al hacer click en el span, la etiqueta antwort que contiene la descripcion se desliza hacia abajo.

```
$('.antwort').toggle();
var data = false;
$('.faq-content span').click(function () {
    if (!data) {
        $('.faq-content img').css(
            'transform', 'rotate(180deg)',
            '-webkit-transform:', 'rotate(180deg)',
            '-moz-transform', 'rotate(180deg)',
            '-ms-transform', 'rotate(180deg)',
            '-o-transform', 'rotate(180deg)'
        );
        $('.antwort').slideDown();
        data = true;
    } else {
        $('.faq-content img').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
        $('.antwort').slideUp();
        data = false;
    }
});
```

```js
    $('.antwort').toggle();
   var data = false;
    $('.faq-content span').click(function () {
        if (!data) {
            $('.faq-content img').css(
                'transform', 'rotate(180deg)',
                '-webkit-transform:', 'rotate(180deg)',
                '-moz-transform', 'rotate(180deg)',
                '-ms-transform', 'rotate(180deg)',
                '-o-transform', 'rotate(180deg)'
            );
            $('.antwort').each(function () {
                $(this).slideDown();
                data = true;
            });

        } else {
            $('.faq-content img').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
            $('.antwort').each(function () {
                $(this).slideUp();
                data = false;
            });
        }
    });
```

```css
faq {
    margin-top: 3em;
}

.faq-content {
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    padding: 1em;
}

.faq-content span {
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
}


.faq-content span:active img, .faq-content span:active img {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.faq-content .arrow {
    width: 10px;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.faq-content img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.faq-content .antwort {
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column is-half">
    <div class="faq-content">
        <div class="column is-full">
            <h2 class="tile">FAQ</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-full">
            <p>title</p>
            <span class="is-flex">
                                    <img class="arrow"
                                         src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Arrow-down.svg/2000px-Arrow-down.svg.png"/>
testtest
                                </span>
            <div class="antwort">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

El problema que se me presen es que al hacer click en cualquier span generado, se despliegan todos(obviamente), y no se como trabajar directamente con cada elemento por separado, es decir que el efecto suceda elemento por elemento.
Alguien me puede dar una idea de como hacerlo?, gracias

Comment: El problema creo que está en `$('.antwort').slideDown();`. Estás desplegando todos los elementos de esa clase. Tendrías que hacer un each e ir asignando el evento `click` a cada `span`. ¿Podrías poner el HTML renderizado para poder hacer un ejemplo sencillo de lo que te digo?

Comment: Como ha dicho @Kiko_L es po culpa de `$('.antwort').slideDown();` para solucionar esto poniendo `$(this)` y luego utilizar el método `.parent()` y `.next()` para cambiar del `.faq-content span` a `.antwort`

Comment: lo que intentado asi             $('.antwort').each(function () {
                $(this).slideDown();
                data = true;
            }); y nada

Comment: El each tiene que ser para bindear el click. ¿Puedes poner en tu pregunta el HTML una vez renderizado?

Comment: estaba en eso ahora mismo,  ya la puse

Comment: Entonces, cuando haces `click en el `span`, ¿qué `<div class="antwort">` quieres mostrar?¿O quieres tener varios span y controlar el clic individualmente? Te lo digo porque en tu HTML ahora mismo sólo hay un span con un div dentro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo sería. He añadido comentarios explicando el código. A ver si te sirve ;)

```js
//Usamos slideToggle y así nos evitamos el slideUp y con la propiedad is(:visible) nos evitamos también la variable data (que entiendo que estás usando para saber si está desplegado o no el div)
$('.antwort').slideToggle();
    $('.faq-content span').each(function(){$(this).click(function () {  
      //En caso de tener varios divs .antwort hacemos un each
      $(this).find('.antwort').each(function () {
        //Le pasamos una función callback para comprobar si el div .antwort es visible y en caso de serlo hacer el rotate de la flecha (hay que acceder al parent ya que le estás pasando el div y la flecha está un nivel por encima
        $(this).slideToggle('slow',callbackFn($(this)));  
      });        

  });
});
    
function callbackFn(ctrl){
  if(ctrl.is(":visible")){               
  ctrl.parent().find('.arrow').css(
    'transform', 'rotate(0deg)',
    '-webkit-transform:', 'rotate(0deg)',
    '-moz-transform', 'rotate(0deg)',
    '-ms-transform', 'rotate(0deg)',
    '-o-transform', 'rotate(0deg)'
  );
  }
  else{
    ctrl.parent().find('.arrow').css(
    'transform', 'rotate(180deg)',
    '-webkit-transform:', 'rotate(180deg)',
    '-moz-transform', 'rotate(180deg)',
    '-ms-transform', 'rotate(180deg)',
    '-o-transform', 'rotate(180deg)'
   );
  }
 }
```

```css
faq {
    margin-top: 3em;
}

.faq-content {
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    padding: 1em;
}

.faq-content span {
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
}


.faq-content span:active img, .faq-content span:active img {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.faq-content .arrow {
    width: 10px;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.faq-content img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.faq-content .antwort {
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VAvG3sHdS5LqTT+5A/aeq/bZGa/Uj04xKxY8KM/w9EE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="column is-half">
    <div class="faq-content">
        <div class="column is-full">
            <h2 class="tile">FAQ</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-full">
            <p>title</p>
            <span class="is-flex">
             <img class="arrow"                                         src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Arrow-down.svg/2000px-Arrow-down.svg.png"/>
testtest           
            <div class="antwort">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            </div>
            <br/>
             <div class="antwort">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            </div>
          </span>
          <br/>
          <span class="is-flex">
             <img class="arrow"                                         src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Arrow-down.svg/2000px-Arrow-down.svg.png"/>
testtest 2          
            <div class="antwort">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            </div>
          </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, estoy aun intentanto entender javascript y no consigo hacer funciones tan complejas aun. Muchisimas gracias

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta que la funcion que has hecho no es compatible con jquery 1.11, y debido a que uso 2 slider en la web que no funcionan con versiones superiores a esta, voy a tener que buscar una solucuion alternativa, maldita sea.

Comment: Acabo de poner la versión 1.11 en el ejemplo y funciona perfectamente. ¿Qué error te da?

Comment: El tema es que no recibo error, por lo tanto el codigo funciona, pero el div .antwort no se despliega.....estoy comparando el codigo por si hay un fallo en alguna etiqueta, pero todo esta aparentemente bien

Comment: Será alguna tontería que se está colando por ahí porque por versión de jquery no debería haber problema.

Comment: Despues de mirar con lupa encontre el fallo, el problema es que en aqui busca el .antwort dentro de el span, y en mi codigo esta fuera. Peeeero ya esta solucionado. Gracias